# Difference between VMWare tools?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esx

I'm currently writing a module for puppet which installs VMWare tools to virtual nodes.

I want to do this via yum and and yum-repo. VMWare have their own repo (http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/3.5latest/rhel5/x86_64/index.html) which I thought I could use, rather than creating my own. But then I noticed that their repo files is alot different than the rpm file used when installing VMWare Tools on the node, via the "Install/upgrade VMWare Tools" in vSphere.

Does anyone know what the real difference is? Does anyone have any preferences?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the, as VMware refers to them, Tools OS-Specific Packaging for the following reasons:

- They work with whatever kernel version you are running (you don't have to run vmware-config-tools.pl after updating the kernel)
- Not having to run vmware-config-tools.pl at all (and taking down the network interface)
- With them in a yum repository (I actually have them in my own repo, as not all of my systems have Internet access), they are more easily upgradeable.

Here's the [VMware Communites](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/general/tools-os-pkg)  site for them.